# How to block in game purchases on Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

Genshin impact has lots of real money in game purchases.  It is apparently not always clear when you are spending real money from the linked Apple account and when this is in-game money.  You can spend a lot of money.

Is there a way to disable real money purchases from within the game?  Or a way from within the linked Apple account?

Answer (score 5):

Spending money involves specifically buying Genesis Crystals in packs. They can only be converted into other in-game currencies in order to acquire items.

> It is apparently not always clear when you are spending real money

Apparently how? Even purchases from the Wish screen require converting Genesis Crystals into Primo Gems.

For Apple specifically, it appears to be possible to disable In-App Purchases directly on the device.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204396

[image: Apple support info]

Comment: Can confirm what is said in this answer: all places where you buy with real money are pretty clear that its a pack that will cost X dollars. Only confusion might be that there is a currency you can buy, but also get slowly by playing the game. But I dont think its possible to unknowingly buy something with real cash.